# Charlie doesn't stand a chance

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm watching Good Luck Charlie. Charlie is a newborn baby; she has three siblings.

Mom has started to work at the hospital. But she feels very guilty. She said to dad,  "What makes me think I can take care of four kids and do my job simultaneously? I'm a terrible mother."

Then she continued,

> With both of us working, poor little Charlie doesn't stand a chance.

stand a chance of what? It was not mentioned. Do you think it is stand a chance of developing well physically and emotionally?

Her oldest kid, standing nearby, after hearing this, said,

> Come on, no one's going solo on this. All us kids are gonna help. If Charlie gets a little messed up along the way, we can all share the blame.

Comment: I don’t think anyone can solve this. It depends on the context, and you do not give enough in the question.

Comment: Ir presumably _doesn't_ mean 'she doesn't stand a chance of survival', so it seems reasonable to assume that it means what you suggest.

Comment: She has started to work at the hospital. But she feels very guilty. "What makes me think I can take care of four kids and do my job simultaneously? I'm a terrible mother."

Comment: It is indeed dependent on context. It might mean "to survive", but it can also mean "a chance of having a fulfilling childhood".

Comment: stand a chance: to grow up like a normal kid

Comment: ...or stand a chance of having a happy childhood, or stand a chance of overcoming whatever obstacles he has, even with the context, an answer might require reading the mother character's mind

Answer (score 1):

The "default complement" in the well-known saying "stand(s)/stood a chance" is *to live* or *to survive*, absent any other context.

> With both of us working, poor little Charlie doesn't stand a chance (to survive).